# having trouble piping values into powershell function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass the results of an LDAP query (computers) into my Powershell function. However, the function only processes one value. Here's some example code:

```
Function Get-ComputerName {
    Param(
        [Alias('Computer','ComputerName','HostName')]
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )]
        [Object[]]$computers
    )
    if(-not($computers)) { Throw “You must supply at least one computer” }

    foreach($computer in $computers) {
        write-host $computer.Name
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU="Devices",dc=FVWM1,dc=Local' -Filter '*' | Get-ComputerName
```

The result is only one computer name printed but there should definitely be more than one. Help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that function process only first value and not only last?

Comment: maybe I should say "one value" instead of "first value" as, technically, I'm not sure where the one that's written out with write-host falls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the pipeline to pass multiple objects into a function, make sure to use the Begin, Process, and End blocks.  After building a $computers object of my own, I can replicate the issue.

```
$computers = @()
$computers += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Name = "Test"
    Note = "TestTest"
}
$computers += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Name = "Test2"
    Note = "TestTest"
}
$computers += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Name = "Test3"
    Note = "TestTest"
}
$computers | Get-InstalledSoftware
```

This yields `test3`

The solution is to simply wrap the internals of the function with `Process {}` like so:

```
Function Get-InstalledSoftware {
    Param(
        [Alias('Computer','ComputerName','HostName')]
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )]
        [Object[]]$computers
    )
    Process {
        if(-not($computers)) { Throw “You must supply at least one computer” }

        foreach($computer in $computers) {
            write-host $computer.Name
        }
    }
}
```